# Lost ability to edit Cloud Storage permissions

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-console

I've lost the ability to edit a bucket's permissions ( I want to enable a bucket to be publicly readable ), but I cannot seem to fund the old icon that used to be clicked on to edit permissions ( the 3 vertical dots ). They seem to have disappeared after one of the last cloud console design updates.

Here's a shot of one of my test projects:

[image]

This is from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_bucketpermission)

[image]

Where did those 3 little dots go?

I am logged in as the project owner and seem to have complete control of the project.

Sorry for the not very code-centric question, but its been puzzling me for a while now.

Comment: If you click on the bucket name, there is a "Share Publicly" button.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've noticed the share publicly button. I'm sure I'm missing something somewhere, but it seems like clicking the 'share publicly' button only applies to files in a bucket, not for the entire bucket itself. I only see the 'share publicly' button once I've clicked on a bucket name and am inside the bucket itself. My intention is to make the bucket public, so that any file subsequently written are also made public. I'm guessing its now preferred to use ACL's when writing the files instead of setting the bucket as a whole?

Comment: You'll need to set the default object ACL for the bucket. I'd recommend using gsutil to do this instead. See [gsutil defacl](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/defacl).

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're missing the bucket menu options (the 3 vertical dots), it might be because:

1. you haven't enabled billing for your project, which is [required to start using Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#pricing)
2. you don't have [sufficient permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/iam#permissions) to edit the bucket's permissions or metadata